# Restructuring the hierarchy of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a nested dictionary in Python, is there any way to restructure it based on keys?

I'm bad at explaining, so I'll give a little example.

```
d = {'A':{'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5],'c':[6,7,8]},
     'B':{'a':[7,8,9],'b':[4,3,2],'d':[0,0,0]}}
```

Re-organize like this

```
newd = {'a':{'A':[1,2,3],'B':[7,8,9]},
        'b':{'A':[3,4,5],'B':[4,3,2]},
        'c':{'A':[6,7,8]},
        'd':{'B':[0,0,0]}}
```

Given some function with inputs like

```
def mysteryfunc(olddict,newkeyorder):
    ????

mysteryfunc(d,[1,0])
```

Where the [1,0] list passed means to put the dictionaries 2nd level of keys in the first level and the first level in the 2nd level.  Obviously the values need to be associated with their unique key values.

Edit:
Looking for an answer that covers the general case, with arbitrary unknown nested dictionary depth.

Comment: With your edit, can you explain what would happen to a more nested dictionary?

Comment: also for your edit: what's the behaviour if you have the same key at different levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator to handle input of arbitrary depth:

```
def paths(d, c = []):
   for a, b in d.items():
      yield from ([((c+[a])[::-1], b)] if not isinstance(b, dict) else paths(b, c+[a]))


from collections import defaultdict
def group(d):
   _d = defaultdict(list)
   for [a, *b], c in d:
     _d[a].append([b, c])
   return {a:b[-1][-1] if not b[0][0] else group(b) for a, b in _d.items()}

print(group(list(paths(d))))
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [7, 8, 9]}, 'b': {'A': [3, 4, 5], 'B': [4, 3, 2]}, 'c': {'A': [6, 7, 8]}, 'd': {'B': [0, 0, 0]}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Input:

```
d = {'A':{'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5],'c':[6,7,8]},
     'B':{'a':[7,8,9],'b':[4,3,2],'d':[0,0,0]}}

inner_dict={}
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k)
    for ka,va in v.items():
        val_list=[]
        if ka not in inner_dict:
            val_dict={}
            val_dict[k]=va
            inner_dict[ka]=val_dict
        else:
            val_dict=inner_dict[ka]
            val_dict[k]=va
            inner_dict[ka]=val_dict
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [7, 8, 9]},
 'b': {'A': [3, 4, 5], 'B': [4, 3, 2]},
 'c': {'A': [6, 7, 8]},
 'd': {'B': [0, 0, 0]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use 2 for loops, one to iterate over each key, value pair and the second for loop to iterate over the nested dict, at each step form the second for loop iteration you can build your desired output:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for k0, v0 in d.items():
    for k1, v1 in v0.items():
        new_dict[k1][k0] = v1

print(dict(new_dict))
```

output:

```
{'a': {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [7, 8, 9]},
 'b': {'A': [3, 4, 5], 'B': [4, 3, 2]},
 'c': {'A': [6, 7, 8]},
 'd': {'B': [0, 0, 0]}}
```